# Get Cassandra node state for bash script

Tags: bash, cassandra, nodetool

I need to get Cassandra node status in some variable for further using it in bash script. How to make thst in most efficient way?

I know that I can get status from

```
# nodetool status
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UJ  10.131.75.142  698.74 KB  256          ?       d032b36b-ffb6-496a-b814-bab399ce8a1f  RAC2
UN  10.131.75.141  729.76 KB  256          ?       739c1e5f-2ff4-4bfa-9ae8-4f64ff061ce9  RAC1
Datacenter: DC2
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.131.75.144  19.12 MB   256          ?       47430976-dee6-40bb-bce2-2a9f8d401aba  RAC2
UN  10.131.75.143  28.98 MB   256          ?       7b3faef4-ba62-4d1d-87f8-9b0b082a0011  RAC1
```

Or (mode value)

```
# nodetool netstats
Mode: NORMAL
Not sending any streams.
Read Repair Statistics:
Attempted: 0
Mismatch (Blocking): 0
Mismatch (Background): 0
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed
Large messages                  n/a         0              0
Small messages                  n/a         0              7
Gossip messages                 n/a         0          12199
```

But maybe exists better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better way:

```
mode=$(nodetool netstats | grep 'Mode')
if [[ $mode != *"NORMAL"* ]]; then
  echo "Aborting backup!"
  exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the most-straightforward way to do this is to wrap nodetool commands inside a Bash script, and pull the specific fields you require with a combination of `grep` and `awk`.  If there is a better way, then I am not aware of it.  And if that's the way you were going to go, then you probably know how to do this all.

But I'll provide an example anyway.  Here's an excerpt from a script I wrote where I needed the IP addresses for  nodes in my cluster to check compaction throughput/stats on them:

```
#!/bin/bash
STATUS_FILE="nodetool_status.txt"
#get IP addresses, store in file
(~/local/$CASS_VERSION/bin/nodetool status 2> /dev/null | grep "UN " | awk '{print $2}' > $STATUS_FILE)

printf "%15s: %3s %4s\n" "IP" "MB/s" "Pending"

while read -r LINE
do
  COMPACTION_THROUGHPUT=$(~/local/$CASS_VERSION/bin/nodetool getcompactionthroughput -h $LINE 2> /dev/null | awk '{print $4}')
  PENDING_COMPACTIONS=$(~/local/$CASS_VERSION/bin/nodetool compactionstats -h $LINE 2> /dev/null | grep pending | awk '{print $3}')
  printf "%15s: %3s %4s\n" $LINE $COMPACTION_THROUGHPUT $PENDING_COMPACTIONS
done < "$STATUS_FILE"
```

Basically, I process the results of a `nodetool status`, send error output to /dev/null, grep for "UN " (because I only care about checking nodes that are up/normal), and I save-off the second field (IP address) in a file.  Then I read that file to process each IP address, grab certain values for from the output of `nodetool getcompactionthroughput` and `nodetool compactionstats`, and display them.

In terms of efficiency, saving-off the output of `nodetool status` into a file, makes that output easily re-useable.  For `nodetool netstats` you would have to run it once for each node in your cluster, whereas `nodetool status` would only need to be called once.

In your case, since "status" is the field you're after, you'll want to find something else to `grep` by (to make it easier to disregard the extra output lines from `nodetool status`).  Perhaps either the token count ("256") or subnet ("10.131.75.") will work for you?